# Word 2016 export to PDF: OTF font comes out as 72 dpi

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, resolution, microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to convert a Word 2016 document to pdf.
It is important that the entire document is in 300 dpi.

However, some of the special fonts I use (OTF) only have a resolution of 72 dpi when I export them to pdf (I have tried with several programs). It seems that Word only sets the resolution of the font to 72 dpi.

Images are as they should be (have adjusted necessary settings)

OTF should be vector based, hence, there should not be problems with resolution.

- I have tried to save as pdf with integrated fonts.
- I have tried to print via primopdf and setting resolution there to 300 dpi.

So, how do I get Word to output fonts in 300-dpi resolution for printing / exporting document to a professional printer?

Comment: Have tried to clarify - have external bureau to print - need to send them a 300dpi document for print - they return the document with the comment that the font / font graphic is in 72 dpi resolution

Comment: Did you try changing your export settings? At the bottom of the save dialog box, there is part that says: "Optimize for:". You select "Standard (publishing online and printing)". Then click on "Options" button and select "ISO 19005-1 complaint (PDF/A)". Also, it will do you well if you reproduce this problem on a test PDF file and upload it here for us to analyze.

Comment: Also if you give us your font names, we can investigate whether they are resolution-locked.

Answer (score 3):

After trying loads of different things converting the fonts to TTF did the trick!
I deinstalled the original OTFs, installed the TTFs and then restarted.

There are different services for the conversion online... I used http://otf2ttf.com which worked just fine for me. Opentype features, etc. should still be intact with this, but I had no time to check everything.

Hope that works for you!

It’s really strange that Word is still not fully supporting OTFs on Windows. (I used Word 2016, Win8) 
The Mac-Version of Word although did export the OTFs just fine, but wasn’t exporting any links within the document :/ - which is apparently a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party software called [DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/).

[DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) is a software that will print your file to a PDF file
I use it to create PDF files on windows computers, anything that can be printed to a printer can be converted/copied to PDF with the free software...

There are some settings, please try and see if it does fit your needs..

If you'd like to merge PDF files as well you can use [PDFSAM Split & Merge basic](http://www.pdfsam.org/)

I hope this answer will be helpful to you...

Comment: The issue isn't how to convert to PDF, it's how to preserve fonts at high res while doing it.  The OP mentions trying a PDF printer.  Are you recommending these resources because you know for a fact that they will accomplish this?

Comment: PDF convertion by DoPDF is doing a good job and I believe it does what you want, you can keep the fonts used in your document as everything in the document you'll convert (print to PDF by DoPDF) will be available to your newly created PDF file, Please try the FREE version.. If you'd like to see a working example,  I can add some screenshots to my answer that will show how to do it..